# How do I scrape my collage result website

Tags: selenium, web-services, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to collect student's result data from my collage's result website -
http://www.bietjhs.ac.in/result2019/GetResult.aspx

so for that, I used the `requests` module from python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.bietjhs.ac.in/result2019/Result.aspx'

values = {'__VIEWSTATE':'/wEPDwULLTEwMTgxNzc0MDlkZPl3fGYoB3mixdEklq4qolYFT0kX',
          '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':'83531E22',
          '__EVENTVALIDATION':'/wEWAwL1j+SrAgK097CQBgLCi9reAwX5Exu+9wGq1/SB++dfh19a1B4s',
          'txtRollNo':'1804310063'}


respond = requests.post(url = url,data = values)

soup = BeautifulSoup(respond.content,features='html.parser')

print(soup.text)
```

And my code interpreted successfully but the site responded with the runtime error.

```
    
         
             
                Runtime Error 
        
             
         
             
         
                    Server Error in \'/result2019\' Application. 
                    
         
                     Runtime Error  
         
                     
         
                     Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 
                    

 
         
                    Details: To enable the details of this specific error message 
        to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration 
        file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

 
         
                     
                
                
                           
                               
         
        <!-- Web.Config Configuration File --> 
         
        <configuration> 
            <system.web> 
                <customErrors mode="Off"/> 
            </system.web> 
        </configuration> 
                      </td> 
                   </tr> 
          
          </table> 
     
                <br> 
                          <b>Notes:</b> The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the &quot;defaultRedirect&quot; attribute of the application\'s &lt;customErrors&gt; configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.<br><br> 
     
                <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc"> 
                   <tr> 
                      <td> 
                          <code><pre> 
     
    &lt;!-- Web.Config Configuration File --&gt; 
     
    &lt;configuration&gt; 
        &lt;system.web&gt; 
            &lt;customErrors mode=&quot;RemoteOnly&quot; defaultRedirect=&quot;mycustompage.htm&quot;/&gt; 
        &lt;/system.web&gt; 
    &lt;/configuration&gt;</pre></code> 
                      </td> 
                   </tr> 
                              </table> 
                <br> 
        </body> 
    </html>
```

So, please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Roll no's lies between 1804310011 to 1804310064.

Answer (score 0):

`__VIEWSTATE` `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR` and `__EVENTVALIDATION` are the session implementation of the server's application. It's something dynamic that can be used only once (or few times, on restricted context)

You should perform two requests: one `GET GetResult.aspx` (to retrieve those parameters) and one `POST Result.aspx` to retrieve results.

Note: before going anywhere further, if I were you, I'll check if i'm allowed to performed such script.

Comment: But the values of __VIEWSTATE __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR and __EVENTVALIDATION remains the same, as many times I open the site.

Comment: You cannot be sure that the `__EVENTVALIDATION` checks does not depends of your environement, which is different from browser and requests.